# Solving nonlinear differential equation with squares

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

I'm solving the following differential equation (here $y$ is a function of $t$ and $a$ is a constant) $$(y')^2 + a^2y^2 = 1.$$ I know that one solution is $$y(t) = \frac{1}{a}\sin(at),$$ but I'm struggling to find if there are any other (complex) solutions. Is there also a more general way to approach such differential equations, specifically since we have squares?

Comment: The DE is autnomous dosent depend on the variable $t$ Separate the DE and integrate.

Comment: @user577215664 so do I solve by using an integrating factor?

Comment: No need for integrating factor separate and integrate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(y')^2 + a^2y^2 = 1$$
$$y' =\pm\sqrt {1- a^2y^2 }$$
No need for an integrating factor separate and integrate
$$\int \dfrac {dy}{\sqrt {1-a^2y^2}}=\pm \int dt$$
For $a\ne 0$. You need to treat the case $a=0$. And the case $1-a^2y^2=0 \implies y=\pm \dfrac 1a$.

Substitute $u=ay$:
$$\int \dfrac {du}{\sqrt {1-u^2}}=\pm a\int dt$$
Substitute $u= \sin x$:
$$\int  {dx}=\pm at+C$$
$$x(t)=\pm at+C$$
$$u(t)=\sin (\pm at+C)$$
$$y(t)=\dfrac 1a\sin (\pm at+C)$$

Comment: This is how I got to the solution I posted (assuming $a\neq 0$). Are there any other (complex) solutions?

Comment: No there aren't other solution @Geigercounter You just forgot the constant of integration $C$.

Comment: $y(t)=\dfrac {\sin (\pm at+C)}{a}$ is the general solution @Geigercounter

Comment: @Gonçalo Yes you're right. I addded it to my answer thanks a lot